# Как записать результат app.url_map.iter_rules() для blueprint в текстовый документ

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

У меня есть blueprint object "api"

api.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
api = Blueprint('api', __name__)
@api.route('/')
def call_api():
    return ""
```

init.py:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from api import api

public = Blueprint('public', __name__)
@public.route('/')
def home():
return render_template('public/home.html')


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(public)
app.register_blueprint(api, subdomain='api')
print(list(app.url_map.iter_rules()))
```

И когда я печатаю:

```
print(list(app.url_map.iter_rules()))
```

Получаю следующий результат:

```
[<Rule 'api|/' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> api.call_api>,
<Rule '/' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> public.home>,
<Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -
```

Но мне нужно записать результат в текстовый документ, так как в результате выше.

Как мне записать  app.url_map.iter_rules() в текстовый документ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала привести в соответствующий вид:

```
rules = map(repr, app.url_map.iter_rules())
```

Затем записать в файл:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(rules))
```

Либо в виде json:

```
import json

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(rules))
```